# Xcode - Scale Font from iPhone to iPad size

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, scale, uifont

I'm trying to create something like a sports app, which contains a scoreboard. I created a View in my storyboard and dragged some UILabels inside the view. Then I added the constraints to the labels.

Now when I run the app on an iPhone the screen looks nice. All fonts and labels have the right size. But on the iPad is looks something like this:

[image: IPAD current]

But it should look like this:

[image: IPAD Should]

How can I scale up the font size and the labels so it looks perfectly on the iPad?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use size classes. Select the label you want to scale, then on the Utilities panel click the tiny '+' button near the "Font" label. In the dropdown list select "regular width" > "regular height". And then in the newly appeared Font setting select a bigger font size:

[image: Size classes]

If you're not using size classes then you have to either change the font size in code (use **UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()** macros to determine whether you're running on iPhone or iPad), or simply create a different storyboard for the iPad interface (add a new storyboard to the project and then in your app's Info.plist add the "Main storyboard file base name (iPad)" key with your new storyboard name as a value)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the font size to be used for each size class. This can be configured in Xcode storyboard editor as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/ChangingtheFontforaSizeClass.html).